# Teste de Variâncias no R

Tags: r

Estou com dúvida no resultado obtido no teste de variâncias no R ao utilizar as amostras e o código abaixo:

```
x1 <- c(264.6, 253.9, 294.8, 225.2, 244.3, 253.7, 254.0)
x2 <- c(284.6, 283.9, 284.8, 285.2, 284.3, 283.7, 284.0)

var.test(x1,x2,alternative = "two.sided")
```

Resultado:

```
F test to compare two variances

data:  x1 and x2
F = 1541.8, num df = 6, denom df = 6,
p-value = 5.441e-09
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  264.9234 8972.8394
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          1541.789
```

Ao observar resultado, o p-valor é `5.441e-09`, ou seja, rejeita-se H0 para a igualdade de variâncias. No entanto, o intervalo de confiança contém o valor da razão das variâncias, discordando do p-valor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note que o teste aplicado aqui é o teste de razão entre as variâncias, que utiliza a estatística F de Snedecor. As hipóteses testadas aqui foram

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que, se

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que a razão estimada entre as variâncias é bastante alta, sendo igual a 1541.789. Assim, o p-valor do teste realizado acabou ficando bastante baixo, fazendo com que a tendência seja rejeitar a hipótese nula. Por exemplo, considerando um nível α = 0,05, a hipótese nula é rejeitada e, portanto, a razão entre as variâncias não é igual a 1 e, portanto, elas são diferentes.

Isso não entra em conflito com o intervalo de confiança. Perceba que o intervalo de confiança contém a razão entre as variâncias, mas a hipótese alternativa diz que `true ratio of variances is not equal to 1`. Mas, de fato, 1 não pertence ao intervalo de confiança, que é dado por (264.9234 8972.8394). Logo, o valor colocado como hipótese nula não pertence ao intervalo de confiança e a razão não é igual a 1. Logo, as variâncias são diferentes. Portanto, não há contradição alguma.